# CIDR Ip range with join or in KQL operation

Tags: kql, cidr

We have a list of IP ranges in CIDR format in one of custom table in Azure Sentinel. We need to map Azure AD SigninLogs with those IP ranges. Is there any way we can map IP Address with CIDR Ip range using operators like in, join etc.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the `ipv4_lookup()` operator:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/ipv4-lookup-plugin

Here's an example:

```
let IPLookup = datatable(cidr:string, country:string)
[
  "111.68.128.0/17", "Japan",
  "5.8.0.0/19",      "Russia",
  "2.20.183.0/24",   "UK",
];
let Logs = datatable(ip:string, status:long, request:string)
[
  "2.20.183.12",   400, "GET /index.html",
  "5.8.1.2",       500, "POST /create.php",
  "192.165.12.17", 400, "GET /index.html",
];
Logs
| evaluate ipv4_lookup(IPLookup, ip, cidr, return_unmatched = true)
```

Results will be enriched with country information based on request IP:

| ip | status | request | cidr | country |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2.20.183.12 | 400 | GET | /index.html | 2.20.183.0/24 |
| 5.8.1.2 | 500 | POST | /create.php | 5.8.0.0/19 |
| 192.165.12.17 | 400 | GET /index.html |  |  |